# Avoid nested loops using list-comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, nested, list-comprehension

I'm wondering if this is a good idea to avoid nested loops using *List Comprehension* in the case bellow

Imagine the following list of names in a `config.py` file

```
# config.py
NAME_LIST = [
    'name1',
    'name2',
    (...)
]
```

I'm using this list of names to go though multiple different directories, and for each of the files I find, I read the content of the files and process data.

**This is my actual code:**

```
import config

def foo():

    for w in config.NAME_LIST:
        folder = "/data/test/{name}/in".format(name=w)
        files = list_files(folder) # return a list of files found in folder

        for f in files:
            content = read_file(folder, f) # read files content
            # (... do some stuff to process data)
```

I really want to avoid a nested loop to keep the code as flat as possible.

I tried to approach this using *List Comprehension* but not sure this is the best solution as I don't want it to return anything.

**Here is what I've done:**

```
import config

def foo():

    def _process(f):
        """function called from list comprehension to avoid doing nested loops"""
        content = read_file(folder, f)  # read files content
        # (... do some stuff to process data)

    for w in config.NAME_LIST:
        folder = "/data/test/{name}/in".format(name=w)
        files = list_files(folder) # return a list of files found in folder
        [_process(f) for f in files] # using list comprehension
```

Are *List Comprehension* a good solution in this case? Any better way to achieve this?

Comment: No, this is absolutely **not** a use-case for a list-comprehension. A list comprehension is for *creating lists*, not as a "one-liner" substitute for for-loops. You create a list and immediately discard it. Just stick to your loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are some hacks with filter or any to avoid the unnecessary output ([Is there a map without result in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080026/is-there-a-map-without-result-in-python)) but the for loop is probably the most idiomatic approach? Is there a reason you want it flat?